# Getting a value from a custom datatype

Tags: haskell

I have a custom data type in Haskell. I have a custom type from which I later want to get a property and output it. In Java I would just go through the properties with the . (dot) operator, however this doesn't work in Haskell. How would I go about doing this?

This is the code I have now

```
data Person = P Name Address
type Name = String
type Address = String

x :: Person 
x = (P "abc" "def")

y :: Name
y = x.Name

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ "The name is: " ++ y
```

Comment: `(\(P name _) -> name) x`

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked, but why the backslash?

Comment: By the way, very recent GHC versions implement [Record Dot Syntax](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0282-record-dot-syntax.rst), enabling something like `x.field1.field2`. This is not something you should learn immediately, though -- learning pattern matching (like that in `case .. of ..`) should be your first priority.

Comment: @Johannes the backslash is how to denote a [lambda](https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function) (aka an anonymous function) in Haskell. I believe (unless this is just folklore?) that the backslash was chosen because it "looks" very roughly like the Greek letter lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching:

```
y = case x of P name _ -> name
y = name where P name _ = x
y = let P name _ = x in name
```

You could write a field accessor function:

```
name (P n _) = n
y = name x
```

The suggestion in the comments of `y = (\(P name _) -> name) x` is doing essentially this; the definition of `name` above is syntax sugar for

```
name = \(P n _) -> n
```

which gives the solution from the comment once its definition is inlined.

Or you could redefine your type with record syntax and have the compiler write your accessor:

```
data Person = P
    { name :: Name
    , address :: Address
    }

y = name x
```

Actually, if you do this, I think I'd probably omit the type aliases.

```
data Person = P
    { name :: String
    , address :: String
    }
```

They are just repeating information already available in the field name, and not actually buying you much; for example, the compiler won't prevent you from accidentally reading a name from one person and storing it in the address of another.